# turn off new user registration emails

Tags: admin, user-registration, pluggable

I would like to turn off the emails that the admin gets when a new user registers.  We are getting a lot of emails because of new registrations (they are legitimate registrations)  but I just don't want to see the email telling me that someone has signed up again and again.

So far I've tried [installing plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-new-user-notifications/) but they don't work.  (support even says they don't work any longer).  When searching around here the only question I was able to find was  [Turn off admin emails for new user registrations](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90311/turn-off-admin-emails-for-new-user-registrations)
which is from three years ago and doesn't seem to work either.  I tried with this code:

```
// Redefine user notification function
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);

    $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
    $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);

    $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your blog %s:'), get_option('blogname')) . "rnrn";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "rnrn";
    $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "rn";


      //  @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), get_option('blogname')), $message);

        if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
            return;

        $message  = __('Hi there,') . "rnrn";
        $message .= sprintf(__("Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:"), get_option('blogname')) . "rnrn";
        $message .= wp_login_url() . "rn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "rn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "rnrn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email')) . "rnrn";
        $message .= __('Adios!');

        wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname')), $message);

    }
}
```

to my theme functions.php (it has the line @wp_mail commented out) and I've even tried to comment out that line in `wp-includes/pluggable.php` but I still am getting the emails.

I'm using WordPress 4.5.3 right now. (UPDATED to 4.6 as part of this process)

I'm trying to be a clear as a can. I don't want the email that goes to the user to stop as they still should get that, but how can I make the email to admin stop?

Comment: Have you tried putting in the plugins folder?

Comment: i didn't know if it would help seeing as i edited the pluggable.php directly.  Is this all i should have to comment out?

Comment: Oops. Meant to post here. You don't want to edit any core files. That's why we use plugins. You can call pluggable  from the plugin, but if it isn't needed, and it rarely is, you can just drop your code into a php file, upload to your plugin directory, activate.

Comment: I'll be back to my office shortly and will help with this if I can.

Comment: are you using WPMU or stand alone?

Comment: I've been testing on a WPMU without being able to replicate. However I setup a stand alone and I see what we're working with.

Comment: i'm using standalone

Comment: I managed to get ALL notices to stop, but we don't want that, but it's a start.

Comment: Line 350 in your pluggable.php is where I'm digging around fyi

Comment: They do not want us to be able to change that lol. You could just create filters at the server level in cPanel.

Account-level filtering & User-level filtering. I'm convinced  there is no resolve to this lol

Comment: Another option is to make your site MultiSite and disable it there.

Comment: hrm, terrible.  thanks fo rall your help though!

Comment: yw np 

You could also create a dummy email address and set a filter to delete them. Or adjust settings in your email client, but that would be limited to web based email services like Gmail to support multiple devices. 

The first solution is how I handle those types of notifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44126/discussion-between-jarmerson-and-rudtek).

Comment: If you don't mind, accept the answer I wrote up. It isn't what you were looking for, but it will do the trick. I really appreciate it.

Comment: i added an up vote, but can't select as an answer as you posted as a comment not an answer?

Comment: It's just beneath these comments :)

Comment: This will jump you to the link. I appreciate it. I will continue working to find a solution on this, but at this time I don't see any light at the end of the tunnel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Generic Pluggable Approach for WordPress < 4.6 (See [@birgire's Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/236301/25324) for > 4.6)**

Pluggable functions are one of the more depressing relics of WordPress's past and come with a slew of intricacies. That directly modifying the core file (which is entirely inadvisable, as @Jarmerson mentioned in the comments) did not work makes me suspect that another plugin in your installation may be overwriting the pluggable.

The `wp-includes/pluggable.php` file is loaded after active plugins and mu-plugins, but before the active theme; this means that the "Pluggable Functions" can only be superseded by declarations in a plugin.

The modification you discovered in the other answer applies to a much older version of WordPress. In the process of replacing any pluggable function, you should start with [the original function as it exists in your installation's version](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1699) (in your case, v4.5.3). In doing so, the solution becomes the following (comments omitted; no lines added, only removed):

```
function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $deprecated = null, $notify = '' ) {
  if ( $deprecated !== null )
    _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '4.3.1' );

  if ( 'admin' === $notify || ( empty( $deprecated ) && empty( $notify ) ) ) 
    return;

  global $wpdb, $wp_hasher;
  $user     = get_userdata( $user_id );
  $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
  $key      = wp_generate_password( 20, false );

  do_action( 'retrieve_password_key', $user->user_login, $key );

  if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';
    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );
  }

  $hashed = time() . ':' . $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $key );
  $wpdb->update( $wpdb->users, array( 'user_activation_key' => $hashed ), array( 'user_login' => $user->user_login ) );

  $message = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
  $message .= __('To set your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
  $message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n\r\n";
  $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

  wp_mail($user->user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password info'), $blogname), $message);
}
```

I've omitted the traditional `if( !function_exists() )` check that typically encapsulates a pluggable override because in this instance a potential duplicate declaration error is desirable - it would indicate that another plugin has overwritten the `wp_new_user_notification()` function before you, and thus that your attempt to do so is being completely ignored.

I'd recommend placing this function in a [mu-plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) as it lessens the chance that another plugin should beat you to the punch. In any scenario, do not modify the core file `wp-includes/pluggable.php` with the above.

Comment: i tried this and get this error:  Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wp_new_user_notification() (previously declared in /home/tdh/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php:1709) in /home/tdh/public_html/wp-content/themes/tdh/functions.php on line 71

Comment: That error is due to the function `wp_new_user_notification()` already being declared. What you have to do is override it by including the `function_exists()` check it's wrapped in. 

If you include this, I believe your function will get priority over the WP core.

Comment: @Jarmerson the function_exists() check does overrides nothing - it completely skips your declaration of the function in the case that the function has already been declared. All it does is suppress a fatal collision error by ignoring your code.

Comment: @rudtek it looks like you dropped my solution into your theme. It *must* be placed in a plugin - pluggable function overrides in a theme will *always* fail.

Comment: He's on a stand alone.  However I just tested your code on a fresh install and IT WORKS!!! :D

@rudtek go into your plugins folder and simply create a new file e.g. `disable-admin-notices.php` and paste this just after the open tag `/*
Plugin Name: Disable Admin Email Notices
*/` then paste bosco's code and activate from plugins. Worked for me.

Comment: @Jarmerson a "mu-plugin" is a "must-use plugin" - plugins placed in a special folder result in them always remaining "activated" and loading earlier than other plugins. No relation to WPMU ;)

Comment: Of course it isn't lol. I'm still learning... Thank you.

Comment: This worked.  it was putting in as a plugin.  Thanks @Bosco!  Thanks @Jamerson too!

Answer (score 9):

**Approach for WordPress 4.6+**

Check out the patch in ticket [#36009](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36009) that was merged into WordPress version 4.6.

It [adds](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/36009/36009.2.diff) the `'user'` option for the `$notify` input parameter of [`wp_new_user_notification()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1dd3ed4bd5bb6c48918c26f934fef89ef8a0550c/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1699), to skip sending those emails to the admin.

**How it works**

The `register_new_user()` function contains this part:

```
do_action( 'register_new_user', $user_id );
```

The email notifications are activated with:

```
add_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
```

where the callback is defined as:

```
function wp_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify = 'both' ) {
        wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, $notify );
}
```

**Workaround**

We could therefore try this approach <strike>(untested)</strike> with a custom callback and remove the default one:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    remove_action( 'register_new_user',   'wp_send_new_user_notifications'         );
    add_action(    'register_new_user',   'wpse236122_send_new_user_notifications' );
} );

function wpse236122_send_new_user_notifications(  $user_id, $notify = 'user' )
{   
    wp_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify );    
}
```

where we change the default from `'both'` to `'user'`.

It's worth mentioning that `wp_send_new_user_notifications()` is also hooked into these actions:

- `network_site_new_created_user`
- `network_site_users_created_user`
- `network_user_new_created_user`
- `edit_user_created_user`

We could deal with them in a similar way as described above.

Comment: this seemed awesome.  I updated to 4.6 and tried, but it still is sending me the new user notification.

Comment: It's listed as a patch and requires unit testing. Untested waters.

Comment: I just tried this on a fresh install with zero plugins and default theme without luck.

Comment: I'm going to keep my eye on this, because this makes so much sense

Comment: @Jarmerson Thanks for testing, I just noticed a small problem with my snippet, I will fix it ;-)  Ps: the unit-test was added [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36009#comment:9).

Comment: @rudtek I just updated the answer, fixed a typo. I just tested it and it seems to work now on my test install.

Comment: Above code not working for me in WP 4.6.1.

Comment: Thanks for your comment  @wired. I tested this successfully on a vanilla install, as a plugin, if I remember correctly. Did you receive a PHP error from the code? It assumes PHP 5.3+.

Comment: I have it on a live BuddyPress site with many plugins so there could be a conflict, I dunno. Just not working. Not able to test it locally.

Comment: It's been a while since I used BuddyPress, so I'm haven't tested this there, but plugins can always interfere. @wired

Comment: I think for some reason, it doesn't hook the action, because your snippet MUST work. I have checked `wp_send_new_user_notifications` and `wp_new_user_notification` in `user.php` and `pluggable.php`.

Answer (score 2):

**After some research I determined that you can disable all notification emails, but not those that send to admin.**

Per your original question, I can offer some advice on how to handle unwanted notification email from WordPress user registration and password reset email.

Assuming you have a cPanel environment running your installation, simply follow these steps and you will have effectively removed those particular email.

Access **Account Level Filtering** from the cPanel admin. In this area you can manage filters for your main account. You want to **Create Filter** and proceed to create a **New Filter** for **All Mail on Your Account**.

In the **Rule** field select **To** and **equals**. *Note: You can also create filters for other conditions*. The last field is a text area which you input the email address you're working with. Below the **rules** area is where the magic happens. Select **Discard Message**. There are also other options.

I've always created an email address I know wont be used and created the filter using it.

I could go on about WordPress pluggable hooks and such, but there is nothing that will do exactly as you would like. Bummer...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
https://gist.github.com/someguy9/b24866f521ec3eb20b13feb4c72a6afd#file-disable-wordpress-admin-new-user-notification-php

```
    <?php
//Disable the new user notification sent to the site admin
function smartwp_disable_new_user_notifications() {
    //Remove original use created emails
    remove_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
    remove_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 2 );
    
    //Add new function to take over email creation
    add_action( 'register_new_user', 'smartwp_send_new_user_notifications' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'smartwp_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 2 );
}
function smartwp_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify = 'user' ) {
    if ( empty($notify) || $notify == 'admin' ) {
      return;
    }elseif( $notify == 'both' ){
        //Only send the new user their email, not the admin
        $notify = 'user';
    }
    wp_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify );
}
add_action( 'init', 'smartwp_disable_new_user_notifications' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are hooks you can use for handling the basic emails sent out:

```
add_filter('wp_send_new_user_notification_to_admin', '__return_false');
add_filter('wp_send_new_user_notification_to_user', '__return_false');
```

That will stop an install from sending emails with the subject pattern "[SITENAME] New User Registration".